# Can an asynchronous call be made before the views are configured?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get JSON data to display in a RecyclerView list, but whenever I try to make the call it seems that the RecyclerView comes up empty.  I have it set up so that I get the API service/manager in onCreate prior to the configViews() method which I wrote.  Am I making the call too early?  I thought the problem would be to create the views/adapter prior to the call, but it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

This is the code for the Retrofit call:

```
 listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Character>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Character>> call, Response<List<Character>> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                List<Character> characterList = response.body();

                Log.v(TAG, response.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < characterList.size(); i++){
                    Character character = characterList.get(i);
                    character.setName(characterList.get(i).getName());
                    character.setDescription(characterList.get(i).getDescription());
                    characterAdapter.addCharacter(character);


                }
                configViews();
                characterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
            else {
                int sc = response.code();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Character>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

And that configViews() method is here, albeit simpler than when I first started (I have been moving bits around to test whether they will affect inflation of the RecyclerView):

```
private void configViews() {

    characterAdapter = new CharacterAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(characterAdapter);

}
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your replies!  As requested here is the Adapter class:

```
public class CharacterAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CharacterAdapter.Holder> {

private static final String TAG = CharacterAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private final CharacterClickListener clickListener;
private List<Character> characters;

//Constructor for CharacterAdapter.
public CharacterAdapter(CharacterClickListener listener){
    characters = new ArrayList<>();
    clickListener = listener;

}


//Inflates CardView layout
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View row = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, 
false);
    return new Holder(row);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

    Character currentCharacter = characters.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(currentCharacter.getName());
    holder.description.setText(currentCharacter.getDescription());

    //Picasso loads image from URL

Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
.load("http://gateway.marvel.com/"+ 
currentCharacter.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return characters.size();
}

public void addCharacter(Character character) {
    //Log.d(TAG, character.getThumbnail());
    characters.add(character);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Character getSelectedCharacter(int position) {
    return characters.get(position);
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener{

    //Holder class created to be implemented by adapter.
    private ImageView thumbnail;
    private TextView name, description;


    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.character_thumbnail);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.character_name);
        description = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.character_description);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        clickListener.onClick(getLayoutPosition());

    }
}

public interface CharacterClickListener {
    void onClick(int position);



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle you have done the right thing. You can instantiate the views before and fire a fetch request. Once you receive the response, you can notify the adapter that the datatset has changed and the adapter will refresh your views.

The only correction here is, you need to call your `configViews();` before the for loop. So your code should be like -

```
configViews();
for (int i = 0; i < characterList.size(); i++){
                    Character character = characterList.get(i);
                    character.setName(characterList.get(i).getName());
                    character.setDescription(characterList.get(i).getDescription());
                    characterAdapter.addCharacter(character);


                }

characterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Because right now what is happening  is you add all your data using add character and then after that you again call config views which reinitialises your adapter at

```
characterAdapter = new CharacterAdapter(this);
```

Hence the empty views.

**PS:** I don't know your adapter's addCharacter method but i am hoping it is doing the right job. If it still doesn't work let me know and then add your addCharacter code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Still coming up blank though, here is the addCharacter() method from the adapter :

`public void addCharacter(Character character) {
        //Log.d(TAG, character.getThumbnail());
        characters.add(character);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

Comment: Ok so where are you passing the characters array to adapter? I mean in adapter's getview method how are you populating it. Now would need the code of your entire adapter as well. Can you add in your question

Comment: Added the adapter class to the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on code the snippets, in configViews() method you are creating new instance of CharacterAdapter. The following code snippets will work.

private void configViews() {

```
//characterAdapter = new CharacterAdapter(this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(characterAdapter);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the call `configViews()` call in `onCreate` but move the rest of it into `onResume`. It'll achieve following:

- Ensure views are ready to display data
- Refresh data if your app was brought to background and re-opened